# Why does Ubuntu query SNMP devices on system startup

Tags: snmp

Yes -- this question has been asked before, but not answered.  I have no "reputation" so I can't add to that thread.  I can add that this is not limited to UPSes. I ran wireshark to see what was happening and Ubuntu does a snmp-get for three OIDs to the broadcast address.

1312 73.377595 172.16.254.109 255.255.255.255 SNMP 115 get-request 1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0 1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0 1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.6.1

As the other thread states, analyzing syslog doesn't lead to any obvious answers.

Does anyone know why Ubuntu would be doing this?

Comment: Hello Scott.  Please add to your question.  What Ubuntu are you on? What are you trying to do and what is happening.  You say "why Ubuntu would be doing this".  Not clear what the problem is.